# Open broadcaster not installing

Tags: apt, ffmpeg

I'm trying to install Open Broadcaster: https://obsproject.com/download#linux

but I'm getting these errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 obs-studio : Depends: libavcodec-ffmpeg56 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable
              Depends: libavdevice-ffmpeg56 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable
              Depends: libavfilter-ffmpeg5 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable
              Depends: libavformat-ffmpeg56 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable
              Depends: libavutil-ffmpeg54 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable
              Depends: libswresample-ffmpeg1 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable
              Depends: libswscale-ffmpeg3 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Not sure how to solve them.

Comment: These steps seem to have worked: https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/wiki/Install-Instructions#linux